# Liquibase gives MySQL Syntax Error where phpMyAdmin doesn't

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tomcat7, liquibase

I want to execute a command on a tomcat 7 server on startup using liquibase 3.2.2 and MySQL 5.6.23.

The command fails with a mysterious syntax error in line 2.

When I execute the same command in the phpMyAdmin GUI it works without a problem.

This is the command:

```
UPDATE `mytable`
SET `parametervalue`='<div class="div_w5 col_fg_head font_bold font_size_nor padding_t4 h_right">
    <input type="radio" id="zahlung_ja" name="zahlung" value="1">
</div>
<div class="div_w5 font_bold font_size_nor padding_t4">
    &nbsp;ja &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="div_w5 col_fg_head font_bold font_size_nor padding_t4 h_right">
    <input type="radio" id="zahlung_nein" name="zahlung" value="0">
</div>
<div class="div_w10 font_bold font_size_nor padding_t4">
    &nbsp;nein &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>'
WHERE ID=23;
```

Note: When I condense the multiline string to fewer lines it works also in liquibase. But this doesn't solve my general problem, as the string shown here is just a stripped-down example for several longer strings which I can't disclose.

Comment: Are you running this inside a [`<sql>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) tag?

Comment: @Jens no, I'm using the [SQL format](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html)

Comment: Ok. There is a parameter `--splitStatements` which you can set `false` (Default is `true`). Actually it is supposed to only split on `;` so it should work with your example but maybe you can give it a try and set it to `false` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Jens thanks for the hint, splitStatements does the trick. Apparently the statements are split by semicolons even if they occur inside multiline strings. I guess this qualifies as a bug in liquibase (or at least something that should be documented).

Comment: I guess splitting sql statements by `;` is a standard thing to do. So I doubt it will classify as a bug. And I wouldn't know how to safely distinguish the `;` inside an sql statement from the real `;`. You could specify a different delimiter with  `--endDelimiter ` though.

Comment: I hope this is obvious, but you probably shouldn't be storing HTML in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the parameter `splitStatements:false` to the changeset header.

The problem was a semicolon inside a quoted multi-line string, which MySQL interprets as part of the string.

But liquibase ignores the SQL syntax, so it splits the command at the semicolon, which leads to incomplete commands being sent to MySQL.

Note: This was pointed out by Jens in a comment to the question.